# How many images Array to make GIF Images in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, gif

I'm still making 60 images array to GIF images Size 320*320. Normally I used third party Library NSGIF on github but still getting app memory warning and crash when used 80 images in to make GIF images process.

```
NSDictionary *fileProperties = @{(__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary: @{
                                         (__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount: @0, // 0 means loop forever
                                         }
                                 };

NSDictionary *frameProperties = @{(__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary: @{
                                          //(__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime: @0.02f, // a float (not double!) in seconds, rounded to centiseconds in the GIF data
                                          (__bridge id)kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime: @0.06f,
                                          }
                                  };

NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:nil];
NSString *savePath = [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"animated.gif"];

CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)savePath, kUTTypeGIF, FrameArr.count, NULL);
CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)fileProperties);

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < ImageArray.count; i++) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        UIImage *CaptureImage = [ImageArray objectAtIndex:i];

        CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, CaptureImage.CGImage, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)frameProperties);
    }
}
if (!CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)) {
}
else
{
    //[shareBtn setHidden:NO];
}
CFRelease(destination);
```

i want to make 80 plus images to GIF..

Comment: Add some code in your question.

Comment: post some code please.

Answer (score 0):

That actually depends on the duration and the framerate of the gif that your are creating. With a GIF you can probably bring down the framerate to 8-10 fps and still see something decent out of it.

Otherwise you can always opt for a different library and hope it has a better performance

Comment: i try fps set to 10 to make GIF but not change my pain to make GIF